JMS issue as Java 8 is migrated to Java 17 with Jakarta 10
I am migrating my java application from Java 8 spring 5.3.x to Java 17, Spring 6.0.0 with JakartaEE 10 feature enabled in open liberty server. I am facing issue with JMS configuration I guess which was working fine in Java 8. I can see in the logs that the code flow is reaching till the Queue trigger but no logs after that step. No exception, no errors, simply the code flow stops.
Could anyone help me with working example of JMS configuration using Java 17, Spring 6.0.0, JakartaEE 10, liberty server.

Maybe this will help?  https://marketaylor.synology.me/?p=1236
